# Questions about a array of pointers in c++

Tags: c++

Hi there i have some questions about pointers and arrays in c++:

when i want to pass an array of pointers in a function i must write:

```
foo(test *ptest[])
```

right?

when i want to delete a array of pointers, does

```
delete ptest;
```

all for me?

when i pass a pointer to another class and the first class make a delete, the pointer is deletete in all classes right?

must i always create a array of a constant size?

Comment: The answers are respectively no, no, no and no. In other words, you need a C++ textbook. Try "Accelerated C++" by Koenig and Moo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, forget about arrays and pointers and tell us what you really want to achieve. You are probably better off using `std::vector<T>` and pass that around by (const) reference, saving you all the headaches of manual resource management and crazy array-to-pointer-decay rules inherited from C.

Now to answer your questions:

> when i want to pass an array of pointers in a function i must write:
>
> ```
> foo(test *ptest[])
> ```
>
> right?

Yes, but remember that array parameters are always rewritten by the compiler to pointers. Your code is equivalent to:

```
 foo(test **ptest)
```

This means that all information about the size of the array has been lost. Moving on:

> when i want to delete a array of pointers, does
>
> ```
> delete ptest;
> ```
>
> all for me?

No. If you acquire via `new[]`, you *must* release via `delete[]`, otherwise you get [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/). Note that deleting an array of pointers only gets rid of the array itself, not any objects pointed to by the pointers stored inside the array.

Again: Forget about arrays and pointers and use the facilities provided by the C++ standard library.

Comment: +1, there are some many questions there that std::vector just *solves*.

Comment: Agree, except for that "saving headaches" part. :) Resource management still needs attention.

Comment: @Kos: Depends on what `T` is. I certainly wouldn't store raw pointers in a vector.

Comment: @Fred- what would you use instead (in C++03)?

Comment: @Kos: Can I use Boost or TR1? ;)

Comment: I believe I'd hear "unique_ptr<T>" if I say "yes" (assume we don't want reference counting)? And is there an elegant solution when we cannot use those?

Comment: @Kos: `unique_ptr` depends on rvalue references and is thus not available in C++03. The classic solutions are `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T> >` and `boost::ptr_vector<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

> when i want to delete a array of pointers, does `delete ptest;` all for me?

Nope. It tries to delete what's been allocated to the address `ptest`. If `ptest` is not something which was allocated dynamically, your program will crash. **You can only call `delete` on the addresses which you have received from `new`.**

> when i pass a pointer to another class and the first class make a delete, the pointer is deletete in all classes right?

Nope, you need to have exactly one `delete` for every `new`. *(yah, there are "smart pointers" which call `delete` for you, but the point still holds.)*

> must i always create a array of a constant size?

Nope. In C++ there's `std::vector` for having arrays of dynamic size (can be used for constant-size arrays too) and in C there's `realloc` for changing a size of an array.

Answer (score 1):

To delete *any* array you need:

```
delete [] ptest; // note the [] part
```

Arrays can be any size you like (within various practical limits) and unless you make copies of an array then you should delete it exactly once (it doesn't matter *where* you do this, so long as you don't try to acess the data afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, without knowing what you're aiming at and any other contextual information, you should use `std::vector<T>` instead and forget about these worries.

That said, to delete any primitive array `arr` you must say

```
delete[] arr;
```

Of course, if the pointers in the array themselves are each the last pointing at heap memory then you should free them first. You can do that nicely with a reusable `Delete` functor:

```
struct Delete {
    template<class P>
    void operator()(P ptr) const { delete ptr; }
};

// ...
std::foreach(arr, arr+ARR_LENGTH, Delete());
delete[] arr;
```

You must of course make sure no two pointers point at the same address. To further simplify things beyond what a `std::vector<T>` can do for you you should consider using a `boost::shared_ptr<T>`; this will allow you to forget about the delicate case in which two pointers point at the same address.

Comment: I neglected the case in which two pointers point at each other; but at this point I'm getting carried away beyond the scope of the question.